# The service returned an invalid token. please contact your IT administrator if this issue persists"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop

When I import data from snowflake to power BI I got an error like this

> "the service returned an invalid token. Please contact your IT administrator if this issue persists " .

How can I resolve this issue

How can I get access to it

Comment: If you are using snowflake, why have you tagged SQL Server..?

Comment: The error suggests the token used for authentication either expired or was revoked by the admin. This is an error message returned by PowerBi. You should get in touch with your Snowflake administrator who configured the authentication from PowerBi to Snowflake.